# Aggregating Data in R Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a csv file similar to below:

Name - Year - Genre - Sales

1    - 2005 - Action  - 1

2    - 2005 - Action  - 2

3    - 2005 - Shooter - 3

4    - 2006 - RPG     - 2

5    - 2006 - RPG     - 2

6    - 2007 - Action  - 1

7    - 2007 - Shooter - 3

8    - 2007 - RPG     - 2

...

My end goal is to make a sand chart in R that shows the total sales of each genre on the y axis and year on the x axis, with the labels being the genres.

I need to sum up the sales of each of the genres per year, for example 2005 sales would be Action:3, Shooter:3, RPG:0. And do this for every year.

This would eventually give me a data frame that looks like this:

```
 Action  Shooter  RPG
```

2005      3      3      0

2006      0          0      4

2007      1          3      2

In Python, I could do this using enumerate, but I'm having a hard time figuring this out in R.

Here's what I have so far

```
vg <- read.csv("vgdata.csv")

genres <- unique(vg$Genre)
years <- sort(unique(vg$Year))

genredf <-data.frame(vg$Genre)
i<-0
for (year in (unique(vg$Year))) {
  yeardata = rep(0,length(genres))
}
```

This would give me the data frame with 0s in it. Now I'm trying to add in the summation of the data so I can chart it.

Sorry for the poor formatting. I'm still new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `xtabs`

```
xtabs(Sales ~ Year + Genre, df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution using `reshape` + `aggregate` (but seems not as simple as the approach of `xtabs` [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61235438/12158757))

```
dfout <- reshape(aggregate(Sales~Year + Genre,df,sum),
                 direction = "wide",
                 idvar = "Year",
                 timevar = "Genre")
```

such that

```
> dfout
  Year Sales.Action Sales.RPG Sales.Shooter
1 2005            3        NA             3
2 2007            1         2             3
3 2006           NA         4            NA
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = 1:8, Year = c(2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L), Genre = c("Action", "Action", "Shooter", 
"RPG", "RPG", "Action", "Shooter", "RPG"), Sales = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: What does Name = 1:8 mean here?

Comment: @madewellmusic That is for your first column `Name`, read from your post